# Polymorphically load subclasses using Spring JPA Repository and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism, repository

I have a superclass Fruit and 3 subclasses Apple, Pear and Banana. I have 3 Spring data CrudRepositories for the 3 subclasses.

Fruit is an abstract superclass annotated with @Entity and @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

I have a FruitRepository with the following method:

```
@Query(value=""
        + "(SELECT * FROM Apple where assignedTo_guid = :guid )"
        + "UNION"
        + "(SELECT * FROM Pear where assignedTo_guid = :guid )"
        + "UNION"
        + "(SELECT * FROM Banana where assignedTo_guid = :guid )", nativeQuery=true)            
List<Fruit> getFruitEntitiesForMasterRef(@Param("guid") Long guid);
```

Essentially i want to query all the fruit subclass tables and then return a list of the superclass. At the moment, this throws the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'clazz_' not found.

Is it possible to do this using Spring Repositories or Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't let you hibernate to do this for you? I mean, hibernate can give you a list with all the subclasses if you create a criteria or an HQL to retrieve all `Fruit` objects in a `List<Fruit>`.

Then, if you want to do *special* processing of each element of the fruit list, you can use a Visitor Pattern.

I wouldn't do this using native queries, hibernate knows how to manage this situation.